# with agile estimating, is it true some say to choose intervals like 1/2 to 1.5 days only?

Tags: agile, scrum, estimation

with agile estimating, is it true some say to choose intervals like 1/2 to 1.5 days only?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a problem unique to software development

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It tends to be a good rule of thumb (agile or not) that your tasks should be broken down into at most 1 - 2 day increments.

The idea is that if you have larger chunks than that then you haven't broken the task down enough and you will more likely miss the estimate and miss it by larger amounts of time than had you broke it down.  Often when you break it down you discover your initial estimate was off and since you have broken the task down into more concrete tasks your estimate is now more accurate, more trackable and meaningful.

For tasks that are coming up on your to do list soon you should pay attention to this but for long range planning where you haven't necessarily thought out the feature in detail I think larger estimates / tasks not broken out for the feature is OK.

Here's a link to Joel Spolsky talking about this. Take a look at item #5 about half way down the page.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000245.html

Comment: We try to break down the tasks as much as possible. In some cases we end up with tasks with an estimate of 15 minutes, others up to 8h. 99 % of the 15 minute tasks are subtasks of other tasks, and more used as a list of things to remember rather than an actual task. In other words - used as a list of things you should not forget. As my customer demand that their developers should report time, the combination of this sort of break down and the use of Jira enable us to report time without spending much time on overhead.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, any estimate that's longer than 2 days is probably hiding serious work that should be broken down further. Such estimates have a very high probability of going over. Try to break everything down into smaller chunks so that no individual chunk costs more than 1-2 days.

Answer (score 3):

There are advantages to keeping the estimates short.  It forces you to break up large tasks into small, discrete tasks that can be measured and discussed quickly, which helps promote the entire Agile development process.

That being said, I almost never keep a "rule" as a hard and fast rule with things like this.  I'd say this is a good guideline, however.

Answer (score 1):

My team consists of junior programmers (university students) and we've found that it's generally easier if we break all the large tasks down into a bunch of smaller ones. It involves more forward-thinking but in the end we are more productive and can it's easier to evaluate our progress. It also brings a sense of achievement when you have something completed at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with that guideline. Anytime I have ever taken on a 5 day task, it has degenerated to a three week nightmare. Large estimates indicate you didn't learn enough about the problem up front to know what is involved, because if you had, you could have found ways to break it up better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree. If a team's iterations are two week long, the 10 days mean that 1 day would be spent for iteration close (show & tell), iteration planning and tasking or planning poker.

When playing planning poker, a team either geometric or Fibonacci progressions for estimates. For example, cards would contain values such as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 or 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13. Each number reflects the number of days of development for a pair of programmers.

For each card, once discussion has occurred, each member simultaneously plays the card that reflects their estimate. If the majority of the team converges on the same estimate, the estimate is accepted. If there is much variation in the estimates, further discussion occurs (members explain the reason for their estimates) and another round of voting takes place. This occurs until consensus is reached.

If a number greater than 8 is picked, then the card is deemed to be too big and the card is refactored into at least 2 smaller cards. The reason being is that such a large estimate indicates the card is too big to be completed in a single iteration and any estimate is very likely to be inaccurate.

Using such a method brings commitment from the team members to delivery all they have committed to and for a new team the estimate become so accurate that carry over of cards soon become a low risk.

Answer (score 0):

A very good post about agile estimation and planning you can find on the blog of agile42: [Just enough, just in time](http://www.agile42.com/cms/blog/2009/07/6/sprint-planning-just-enough-just-in-time/)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers here, so I'll play devil's advocate and approach it from a different side.

There's a possible problem with breaking down things into very small estimates (# of hours) when doing things such as release planning. David Anderson discusses it in his (excellent) book [Agile Management for Software Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131424602).

Basically, the idea is that with a task that is very small, a developer will pad his estimate by a fair bit (say, turning a half hour into an hour, or doubling it) because of a certain amount of ego that would be bruised if the developer failed to complete such a small task in the estimated time. These local buffers add up quite a bit and result in a global buffer that's far bigger than it needs to be.

This is less of a problem if you stick with .5 days as a min - it's basically assumed that there's some buffer in there, so you won't need to pad it any more.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a bit of mix of information and overlapping in this thread... allow me to make my point :-)

1) The Fibonacci sequence, that is very much use through the Planning Poker technique from Mike Cohn, is about estimating "Complexity" of User Stories, which are - as Cam said - normally written on cards, and entail more than one task, at least all of those which will be needed to make a Story shippable (Ken Schwaber, Alistar Cockburn, Mike Cohn...)

2) The tasks that are included to complete a Story, are normally estimated in Ideal Hours or Pomodori (Francesco Cirillo, "The Pomodoro technique"). If you estimate in Ideal Hours normally the rule of thumb is to keep them between 1/2 day (3 ideal hours) and 2 days (12 ideal hours) of work. The reason for this is that doing so the team will have more qualitative status information by having at least every two days a team member reporting a Task as done, which is much more "valuable" than a 60% done. If you use Pomodori they are implicitly "timeboxed" to 25 min. each

The reason to keep tasks small comes basically from the "Empirical Process Control Theory" for which through transparency and regular inspection & adaption, you can better check the progress of your work, by quantifying it. The goal of having smaller tasks is to be able to clearly describe and envision in details what will be actually done, without adding too much of "guessing" given to the natural uncertainty deriving from having to predict "the future". Moreover defining an outcome and a shorter timebox allow people to keep the focus with enough "sense of urgency" to make it a challenging and motivating experience.

I would also catch up the point of the "motivation" and "ego" - from Chris - by adding that a good way to have people committed and motivated is to define the expected outcome of a task, so to be able to measure the results upon completion, and celebrate the success. This idea is encapsulated in the Pomodoro Technique, but can be achieved also using ideal hours for estimation. Another interesting part of the Pomodoro Technique is that "breaks" are considered "First Class Citizens" and planned regularly, which is very important especially in creative and brain intensive activities :-)

What do you think?
Best
ANdreaT